# Awful smell when reversing AND fully cranking the wheel

Tags: subaru, smell, forester

I drive a used 2004 Subaru Forester (owned for 2.5 years now).  The clutch went out last summer so that's been replaced.  I've experienced the aforementioned issue only a few times when both the reverse gear and cranking the wheel hard are engaged.  No issues with just reverse and no issues with just fully cranking the wheel-- only when both are happening simultaneously.  After a minute or two, the smell dissipates.  I'm sorry, but I can't identify what kind of smell (rubber, oil, rotten egg, etc.).

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there any strange noise associated with the smell? Is there any screeching or whining from the engine bay?

Comment: Manual transmission or automatic?

Comment: Manual. 5 speed.